# How to handle long requests in Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have hosted my node app in Cloud Run and all of my requests served within 300 - 600ms time. But one endpoint that gets data from a 3rd party service so that request takes 1.2s - 2.5s to complete the request.

My doubts regarding this are

1. Is 1.2s - 2.5s requests suitable for cloud run? Or is there any rule that the requests should be completed within xx ms?

Also see the screenshot, I got a message along with the request in logs **"The request caused a new container instance to be started and may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request"**

2. What caused a new container instance to be started?
3. Is there any alternative or work around to handle long requests?

Any advice / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Google Cloud run new instance started]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I don't think that will be an issue unless you're worried about the cost of the CPU/memory time, which honestly should only matter if you're getting 10k+ requests/day.  So, probably doesn't matter and cloud run can handle that just fine (my own app does requests longer than that with no problem)
2. It's possible that your service was "scaled to zero" meaning that there were no containers left running to serve requests.  In that case, it would be necessary to start up a new instance and wait for whatever initializing/startup costs are associated with that process.  It's also possible that it was auto-scaled due to all other instances being at their request limits.  Make sure that your setting for max concurrent requests per instance is set greater than one - Node/Express can handle multiple requests at once.  Plus, you'll only get charged for the total time spend, not per request: [image]
3. In situations where you get very long (30 seconds, minutes+) operations, it may be a good idea to switch to some different data transfer method.  You could use polling, where the client makes a request every 5 seconds and checks if the response is ready.  You could also switch to some kind of push-based system like WebSockets, but Cloud Run doesn't have support for that.

TL;DR longer requests (~10-30 seconds) should be fine unless you're worried about the cost of the increased compute time they may occur at scale.

Comment: Cloud run can handle request up to 900s (15 min) and maybe more in future. Can you confirm that long request is triggered by user?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, one endpoint gets data from 3rd party service, so the endpoint request is user triggered

Comment: @Ameo Helpful answer, this seems okay for me, is there any relation between time taken to handle request and new container starting?

Comment: Yes, when you scale to 0, or when a new instance is required, a new container start, it's called cold start. The request processing take the cold start + the normal request processing. By the way, if you have a 30s of container start and 10ms of processing, the first request takes 30010ms, the following only 10ms. Try to minimize the cold start!

Comment: @CaptainAdmin I can't say for sure, but I think the primary metric used to determine that is the number of requests and the capacity of currently running instances.  I know that they also use some heuristics under the hood to anticipate demand and pre-start instances, but I don't think the details are public.

Comment: BTW, Is it a good idea to keep the instance warm by make use of cloud scheduler to ping every X minute? Any idea about how much time of inactivity makes instance goes to sleep?

Comment: @CaptainAdmin that is an option if the cold starts are a problem for your use case.  However, I'd look into how bad they actually are and see if you really need them.  Most cold starts I've seen are well under 5 seconds, usually far less at around 1-2 seconds or less.

Comment: @Ameo Cold starts usually takes 2.5s , but I am getting container started message everytime even in the middle of frequent requests